# App deauthorization: Is there any triggered event by which I can update fbsr cookie without reloading page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

My first post here ! :)

Situation:

- User authorized the app and while using it, in the next tab he is removing app from settings   page (app deauthorization).

Why:

- I want authorize every function call through existing fbsr cookie where its existence is a proof of user login status.

Other solutions:

1. I can do it using signed request passed in every Canvas POST but I don't want to mix it :)
2. Before every each call I can refresh login status by FB.getLoginStatus() method
3. ... check every user_id from sr with database entries (what anyway must be done), it's ok but not straight ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just check `me/permissions` every time you want to verify your user...

```
FB.api('/me/permissions', function(response) {
    var ra = response['data'][0];
    pPublishStream = (ra['publish_stream'] == 1);
    pCreateEvent = (ra['create_event'] == 1);

    if (pPublishStream && pCreateEvent) {
        // yay!!!
    }
});
```

**Edit:** In retrospect, my answer above solves the issues you mentioned but **also** catches the case where the user removes individual permissions for the app. So maybe it's not exactly what you wanted.

Comment: Saying "function call" I meant client (RESTful) communication with server.

Comment: Are you saying you want to perform the check on the server, not the client?

Comment: Well you can do the same exact thing on the server. In PHP:

Comment: `$perms = $facebook->api('/me/permissions');`

Comment: btw, I prefer to just check the signed_request and ignore the case that you are concerned about. Most users are not going to do what you are describing.

Comment: Your solution I can achieve with invoking FB.getLoginStatus() method before the call which, if the app will be deauthorized, it will not set the cookie.

Comment: Well, you are right, but better be prepared ;) I will not complicate: authorize calls with fbsr cookie, read the user id, if exists in db permit the call, maybe add option with refreshing cookie: if ((current_time - cookie_creation_time) =< 30s) :) Thanks for your reply ! :)

Comment: If you want to be totally prepared, then assume that your user can hack *FB.getLoginStatus()* because anything from the JavaScript can easily be modified by the user.